# form views only allow certain people to view them

Tags: infopath, custom-form, form

I have 4 views, 2 for a manager user and 2 employee views. I am wanting it so when either of them open the form up, they can only see the views associated with them.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sharepoint group for Manager (i.e. Corp_Manager) and Employee(i.e. Corp_Employee). Then on each view, do the following:

1. Go to the SharePoint View.
2. Edit the Page.
3. Edit the Web Part of the view.
4. Under Advanced Options, there should be a Target Audience field there.
5. Put the name of the SharePoint Group that should have access on that view.
6. Click Apply and OK then Stop Editing.

Let me know if you have additional questions. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom solution provided by SPGuys. It will allow you to set permissions at View Level as well as Column Level.

[SPGuys Column and View Permissions](https://sp2013columnpermission.codeplex.com/)